# java.awt.Robot is not functioning as expected

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I have the following code:

```
autoPlay = new Robot();
autoPlay.setAutoDelay(500);
autoPlay.mouseMove((game.getLocationOnScreen().x + 1), (game.getLocationOnScreen().y + 1));
autoPlay.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
autoPlay.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
autoPlay.mouseMove((game.getLocationOnScreen().x + 381), (game.getLocationOnScreen().y + 1));
autoPlay.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
autoPlay.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
autoPlay.mouseMove((game.getLocationOnScreen().x + 1), (game.getLocationOnScreen().y + 381));
autoPlay.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
autoPlay.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
autoPlay.mouseMove((game.getLocationOnScreen().x + 381), (game.getLocationOnScreen().y + 381));
autoPlay.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
autoPlay.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
autoPlay.mouseMove(currentX, currentY);
```

According to the code, the robot should move to the top left corner of a JPanel that I have called `game`. Then it should press and release the left mouse button. Then it should move to the top right corner and press/release the left mouse button. Then it should move to the bottom left corner and press/release the left mouse button. Then it should move to the bottom right corner and press/release the right mouse button. Finally, it should move back to the top left corner.

However, what is happening is that the Robot moves to the corners but doesn't click. It only clicks once when it moves back to the top left corner at the end of the code. I am wondering if my JDK/SDK is the source of the problem or if I don't understand the Robot class.

Comment: Try using `MouseEvent.BUTTON1` instead of `InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK`

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid combination of button flags

Comment: I checked my ActionListener. `if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {` doesn't that work?

Comment: Where'd the `ActionListener` come from?  Where is that in the code sample?

Comment: Why does the Robot still do one click at the end then? I'm very sure that I added the correct Listeners. I added a message to printout whenever the mouse does a click. The mouse is clicking four times in the appropriate spots but the JPanel is not registering the click (the JPanel is supposed to repaint if clicked).

Comment: Besides, `ActionListener`s don't record what triggered them, just that they occurred.  `ActionEvent` doesn't have a `getButton` method??

Comment: Clicks 4 times for me.  Show us the code

Comment: `e` is a `MouseEvent`.

Comment: In an `ActionListener`?

Comment: I think that it's just horrible lag. The code moves to the four corners, moves back to the top left corner, then displays this: Mouse clicked a component at (1, 1)
Mouse clicked a component at (381, 1)
Mouse clicked a component at (1, 381)
Mouse clicked a component at (381, 381)

Comment: Sounds like you're running the `Robot` in the EDT, see the answer I've done, it runs `Robot` in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work just fine for me, maybe it's your mouse listeners?

**Updated**

Tested under Java 6 & Java 7, changed `BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK` to `BUTTON1_MASK` as Java 6 didn't seem to like it...go figure

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestRobot02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestRobot02();
    }

    public TestRobot02() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                TestRobot02.TestPane testPane = new TestRobot02.TestPane();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(testPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                new Thread(new TestRobot02.RobotThread(testPane)).start();

            }
        });
    }

    public class RobotThread implements Runnable {

        private TestPane component;
        private Robot autoPlay;

        private RobotThread(TestPane component) {
            this.component = component;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestRobot02.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                autoPlay = new Robot();

                autoPlay.setAutoDelay(500);
                autoPlay.mouseMove((component.getLocationOnScreen().x + 1), (component.getLocationOnScreen().y + 1));
                autoPlay.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                autoPlay.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                autoPlay.mouseMove((component.getLocationOnScreen().x + component.getWidth() - 1), (component.getLocationOnScreen().y));
                autoPlay.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                autoPlay.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                autoPlay.mouseMove((component.getLocationOnScreen().x + 1), (component.getLocationOnScreen().y + component.getHeight() - 1));
                autoPlay.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                autoPlay.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                autoPlay.mouseMove((component.getLocationOnScreen().x + component.getWidth() - 1), (component.getLocationOnScreen().y + component.getHeight() - 1));
                autoPlay.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                autoPlay.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

                Component child = component.getComponent(0);
                Point pos = child.getLocationOnScreen();
                Dimension size = child.getSize();
                pos.x += size.width / 2;
                pos.y += size.height / 2;
                autoPlay.mouseMove(pos.x, pos.y);
                autoPlay.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                autoPlay.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

                //                autoPlay.mouseMove(currentX, currentY);
            } catch (AWTException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Mouse Clicked at " + e.getPoint());
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Mouse Pressed at " + e.getPoint());
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Mouse Released at " + e.getPoint());
                }

            });

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton("Click me");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("I was clicked :D");
                }
            });
            add(btn);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }
}
```