# How to move the mouse cursor and apply a left click?

Tags: java

In Java I am trying as following, but none is working (even though it compiles well). What is that I am doing wrong?

[image]

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
public class kiosk {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Robot robot = new Robot();
      // Move the cursor 
      robot.mouseMove(300, 500);
      // And then, Left Click
      robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
      robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to read warning at line # 14 please.

Comment: Try using `setAutoDelay` and/or `BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK ` as demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237647/java-awt-robot-is-not-functioning-as-expected/15237833#15237833)

Comment: Sir, i tried but still same problem no error and no actions: http://i.imgur.com/RFsLOGH.png

Comment: Sir, thank you, its working. I was using remote access as a result i could not notice the cursor.